# How can I make a for loop to draw rectangles in a meta tic tac toe board to be used for buttons that are the correct size and place?

Tags: java

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.applet.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

  public class MetaTicTacToe extends Applet implements MouseListener {
  Graphics buffer;
  Image img;
  protected int height, width;
  Rectangle[][] rectangles = new Rectangle[9][9];
  int[][] squarecheck = new int[9][9];
  //False = X, True = O
  boolean turn;


  public void makeButtons() {
    height = getSize().height;
    width = getSize().width;
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      //   rectangles[x][y] = new Rectangle(width/9+10

      }
    }
  }


  public void init() {
    //0 = Empty
    //1 = X's
    //2 = O's
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        squarecheck[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
    addMouseListener(this);
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    height = getSize().height;
    width = getSize().width;
    //Larger 3x3 
    g.drawRect(10,10,width-20,height-20);
    g.fillRect(10,height/3,width-20,5);
    g.fillRect(10,height/3*2,width-20,5);
    g.fillRect(width/3,10,5,height-20);
    g.fillRect(width/3*2,10,5,height-20);

    //TopLeft 3x3 
    g.drawLine(15,height/9,width/3-5,height/9);
    g.drawLine(15,height/9*2,width/3-5,height/9*2);
    g.drawLine(width/9,15,width/9,height/3-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*2,15,width/9*2,height/3-5);

    //LeftMiddle 3x3
    g.drawLine(15,height/9*4,width/3-5,height/9*4);
    g.drawLine(15,height/9*5,width/3-5,height/9*5);
    g.drawLine(width/9,height/3+10,width/9,height/3*2-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*2,height/3+10,width/9*2,height/3*2-5);

    //BottomLeft 3x3
    g.drawLine(15,height/9*7,width/3-5,height/9*7);
    g.drawLine(15,height/9*8,width/3-5,height/9*8);
    g.drawLine(width/9,height/3*2+10,width/9,height/3*3-15);
    g.drawLine(width/9*2,height/3*2+10,width/9*2,height/3*3-15);

    //TopMiddle 3x3
    g.drawLine(width/9*4,15,width/9*4,height/3-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*5,15,width/9*5,height/3-5);
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9,width/3*2-5,height/9);
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9*2,width/3*2-5,height/9*2);

    //Middle 3x3
    g.drawLine(width/9*4,height/3+10,width/9*4,height/3*2-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*5,height/3+10,width/9*5,height/3*2-5);
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9*4,width/3*2-5,height/9*4);
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9*5,width/3*2-5,height/9*5);

    //BottomMiddle 3x3
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9*7,width/3*2-10,height/9*7);
    g.drawLine(width/3+10,height/9*8,width/3*2-10,height/9*8);
    g.drawLine(width/9*4,height/3*2+10,width/9*4,height/3*3-15);
    g.drawLine(width/9*5,height/3*2+10,width/9*5,height-15);

    //TopRight 3x3
    g.drawLine(width/9*7,15,width/9*7,height/3-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*8,15,width/9*8,height/3-5);
    g.drawLine(width/3*2+10,height/9,width-15,height/9);
    g.drawLine(width/3*2+10,height/9*2,width-15,height/9*2);

    //RightMiddle 3x3
    g.drawLine(width/9*7,height/3+10,width/9*7,height/3*2-5);
    g.drawLine(width/9*8,height/3+10,width/9*8,height/3*2-5);
    g.drawLine(width/3*2+10,height/9*4,width-15,height/9*4);
    g.drawLine(width/3*2+10,height/9*5
```

I'm attempting to write a meta tic tac toe program and am currently working on getting buttons to work to register when an x or an o is selected in a square. How can I write these buttons with a for loop so they can be correctly scaled to size of the board at the time?

Answer (score 0):

For this we usually use `LayoutManager`s. They can be nested to get the desired behaviour. Here is how an implementation of a game panel could look like. It uses buttons and in order that it looks good you have to ensure that the width is the same as the height:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

  private int size, count;
  private JButton[] buttons;
  private ClickListener listener = null;
  private boolean[] occupied;

  public GamePanel(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    reset();
  }

  public void reset() {
    removeAll();
    count = 0;
    buttons = new JButton[size * size];
    occupied = new boolean[size * size];
    setLayoutManager(new GridLayout(size, size));
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i] = new JButton();
      buttons[i].addActionListener(new MyActionListener(i));
      add(buttons[i]);
    }
  }

  public void setClickListener(ClickListener cl) {
    this.listener = cl;
  }

  public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].setEnabled(b);
    }
    super.setEnabled(b);
  }

  // TODO add getters ... ommitted

  public interface ClickListener {
    public void buttonClicked(int index);
  }

  private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int i;    
    public MyActionListener(int i) {
      this.i = i;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      if (occupied[i])
        return;
      buttons[i].setText(count++ % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O");
      occupied[i] = true;
      if (listener != null)
        listener.buttonClicked(i);
    }
  }

}
```